# Calendar Start Date must be before End Date

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I have an event that's set for:
Start Time: 08/26/2023 **10:00PM**
End Time: 08/27/2023 **2:00AM**

This is for a front-end form creation for public use.

I'm getting this error "*Start Date must be before End Date*" when I set the start time at a later time than the end time. But this is a valid date for an event I'm trying to publish.

I'm already working with modules for Calendar, but I'm not sure how to fix the ruling for this.

Comment: Hi Shayne, can you elaborate on an event where start time occurs AFTER the end time? I honestly can't think of a use case where this would make any sense and it doesn't sound like something the ruling should be editable for.

Comment: @cherrykoda Hello! It's a night event that spans through midnight. The date is from the 26th-27th from 10pm to 2am the morning after. The back-end event creation accepted this date wherein front-end form unfortunately does not.

Comment: thanks for the context! I think the issue you're running into is that the Calendar module (is this custom or are you using a plugin?) isn't evaluating the entire date and is only comparing the times. Your start and end should be a full date.

In the CMS, be sure that you changed the end date to the day after in addition to adding the time.